# Regression Outputs differ in R and In Python when using the same dataset

Tags: python, r, statistics, regression

So I ran a OLS regression in python and got a very high adjusted r^2 value (.94ish) so I thought to run it in R, because that usually where I run statistical analysis. Oddly enough I got a normal adjusted r^2 (~0.05). Why would the codes give me such different vales?

[Data can be found here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OgfarJdHHfh59Zkn_gGt5HyeOAsZ9Wo-idmpnmeDVWQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Below is the code and a screen shot of each output:

```
tlm <- lm(avg_ambiguous_score ~ crttotal + nfcc_mean + bficonmean+bfiopmean, data = test)
summary(tlm)
```

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

X = df[['crttotal','nfcc_mean', 'bficonmean', 'bfiopmean']]
Y = df['avg_ambiguous_score']
model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
model.summary()
```

[image: OLS in R output]

[image: OLS in Python output]

Comment: The python model has omitted the intercept.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming issue, but merely a theoretical issue:

The R^2 statistic is ill-defined whenever you omit an intercept term.

Edit: Explanation:

R^2 is based on a decomposition like
Total SS = Explained SS + Residual SS (SS=sum of squares).
Now this additive decomposition is mathematically only true if the model contains an intercept. (it is related to the fact that the residuals sum to zero, if the model contains an intercept)

Comment: Could you explain why having the intercept would effect the r^2 to that degree? Found answer on how to add the intercept (link below). Does that look right to you? https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html